# Navigation Drawer xml error

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

Dear stackoverflowers,

I'm using navigation drawer inside my activity, here's the xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#3a3a3c" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/border" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvretailers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Retailers"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/border" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:background="#3a3a3c" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer_retailers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="#3a3a3c" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

However, once i run the application i get an xml error:

```
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidarabia.phones/com.androidarabia.Lebanon.LebanonDrawer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:844)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1048)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at com.androidarabia.Lebanon.LebanonDrawer.selectItem(LebanonDrawer.java:104)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at com.androidarabia.Lebanon.LebanonDrawer.onCreate(LebanonDrawer.java:63)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
08-18 01:36:47.751: E/AndroidRuntime(26527):    ... 11 more
```

Before i had only one listview in the FrameLayout, and it worked properly, but after some modification i wasn't able to get it work! hope you can help! thanks alot stackoverflowers =)

Whole codes:

```
public class LebanonDrawer extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment Lebanon = new Lebanon();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer_retailers);
        String[] songsArray = { "Do", "RE", "MI", "FA", "SO", "LA", "SO" };
        MenuListAdapter mla = new MenuListAdapter(this, songsArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mla);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Lebanon);
            break;

        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Save and clean your project. The problem will be gone.

Comment: @vikram didn't work, i even tried to restart eclipse with null result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams 
                   cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```

In your xml layout, `mDrawerList` is not a direct descendant of `DrawerLayout`. Instead, its a descendant of `FrameLayout` whose LayoutParams are being used.

In your current setup, assign an id to the FrameLayout that holds the ListView, find it in your activity, and use it in:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(frameHoldingListView);
```

Make similar changes for mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(...) and mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(...).

Comment: @KingOmar What's on line 104 and line 63 of `LebanonDrawer.java`?

Comment: line 61 - 64 :
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   selectItem(0);
  }

line 104:
  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

Comment: Ok did everything you said:

08-18 02:15:30.211: E/AndroidRuntime(32358): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidarabia.phones/com.androidarabia.Lebanon.LebanonDrawer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: That's great! I forgot that I am using FrameLayout. Thanks for your supported.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody has a similar problem using Toolbar and:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLayout);
```

by following the training at developer.android.com

Try:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

To save a lot of time searching for the exception's solution:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams 
                   cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```