# What do you need to pass to v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen()/.openDrawer()/.closeDrawer()

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I've been trying to move my code across to the `DrawerLayout` as suggested by android [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) as `SlidingDrawer` is deprecated.

My problem is that so far `DrawerLayout` seems to be either very badly implemented, has unhelpful error messages (no defensive programming) and/or isn't explained well enough in the documentation.

the `isDrawerOpen()` method is described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen(android.view.View)):

> **public boolean isDrawerOpen (View drawer)**
>
> Check if the given drawer view is currently in an open state. To be
>   considered "open" the drawer must have settled into its fully visible
>   state. To check for partial visibility use
>   isDrawerVisible(android.view.View).
>
> Parameters: drawer - Drawer view to check
>
> Returns: true if the given drawer view is in an open state

Each of the methods `isDrawerOpen(View drawer)`, `openDrawer(View drawer)` and `closeDrawer(View drawer)` don't work when passed: The `DrawerLayout` in question or either of it's children. I have no idea what I'm supposed to feed into these methods to allow them to function. Can someone let me know?

See below for entire problem description with implementation.

I have a layout like so:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainmenuPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dualPane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuPane"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And in my code I have the following method hooked up to a button:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    ...
    mMenuPanel = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainmenuPanel);
    ....
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    if(mMenuPanel != null) {
        return mMenuPanel.isDrawerOpen(mMenuPanel);
    }
    return false;
}
```

However if you give it itself as an argument (which would be redundant in the extreme) you get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11241): java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to 
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```

(Which as you'll notice, doesn't give you any information about what you did wrong. It is instead a symtom of the problem).

Other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940333/726954) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18294083/726954) are either incomprehensible or very closely tied to the question without much explanation. Even so I've tried adding a faux `LinearLayout` or one the `DrawerLayout`s children and each give **this** error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11424): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
View android.widget.FrameLayout{420f5ea8 V.E..... ........ 
0,0-800,1172 #7f060038 app:id/menuPane} is not a drawer
```

Can anyone explain what these methods *actually* need to have passed to them to work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

And, the answer:

The second child (aka, the "Drawer") is what needs to be passed to the methods. My problem was that by the time I had figured that out I'd reduced the layout to as simple as possible implementation to test - I'd removed the gravity from the "drawer". Without a gravity, you get the above completely unrelated error messages.

I can confirm I got the code to work using the following setup:

```
mMenuPanel.isDrawerOpen(findViewById(R.id.drawer));
```

and with the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainmenuPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="start"/> <!-- This line was the problem!!!!!!!-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Yes. If you look at the source for `DrawerLayout`, the `isDrawerOpen(...)` method makes a call to `isDrawer(...)` to check the `View` it's being passed is a drawer. The criteria is to check if the `View` has a `layout_gravity` of either `Gravity.LEFT` or `Gravity.RIGHT`. The "start" `layout_gravity` is an alias which can be used for determining which side the drawer is anchored. With RTL (right to left) languages it would be `Gravity.RIGHT` for LTR languages it's `Gravity.LEFT`. If none of those are set for the `View`, the `isDrawer(..)` method returns false.

Comment: Thank you man! In my case I was confused about which gravity to use. Not ```android:gravity``` but ```android:layout_gravity```!

Comment: Wow, this whole time it wasn't working for me because I forgot the `layout_gravity`.  +10 if I could.

Answer (score 14):

if you want to avoid references to views or layouts in order to call **isDrawerOpen**, another way can be applied.

In this case you have to indicate the Gravity:

```
mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START);
```

Being **mDrawerLayout** a reference to your DrawerLayout.

as you said, don't forget `android:layout_gravity="start"`

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity if you have a reference to the DrawerLayout and in this case the FrameLayout with the id R.id.menuPane you can also do...

```
DrawerLayout mMenuPanel = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainmenuPanel);
FrameLayout mMenuPane = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuPane);
mMenuPanel.isDrawerOpen(mMenuPane);
```

Basically you have to pass in a reference to the view being used as the drawer within the DrawerLayout, which will always be mMenuPanel.getChildAt(1) anyways.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the drawer layout from the support library as we can see from your question that you are, there is also the method:

```
closeDrawers()
```

This will close all open drawers (which is usually just the one).