# Java Illegal Argument Exception android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am having this kind of error, after searching for possible resources still does not work.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.ExpandableListView{416b0bc8 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-480,0 #7f080005 app:id/lvExp} is not a drawer
```

Heres my code:

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private LinearLayout linear;
Button btn;

HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prepareListData();

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!drawer.isDrawerOpen(expListView))
        {
            drawer.openDrawer(expListView);
        }
        else
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(expListView);
        }

        }
    });

    // get the listview


    // preparing list data


    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

FOR XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f4f4f4" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_home" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drawer"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->

         <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your logcat.?

Comment: cannot post logcat due to limited reputations, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are getting exception on `if(!drawer.isDrawerOpen(expListView))` expListView list is not a drawer. thats why you are getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:`

try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289395/what-do-you-need-to-pass-to-v4-widget-drawerlayout-isdraweropen-opendrawer) you will get some idea.
for more information [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen%28android.view.View%29)