# Cast exception with android drawers

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

Ave,

i'm learning Android Drawers from:
"http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/"
and i encountered a weird problem. When application start it throws:

```
05-13 12:50:08.325    2030-2030/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lanceit.haito.lanceit, PID: 2030
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1100)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1350)
            at com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.activities.HubActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(HubActivity.java:183)
            at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2838)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(FragmentActivity.java:469)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivity.java:284)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:204)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivity.java:256)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:458)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnPreparePanel(ActionBarActivity.java:280)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onPreparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:84)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1006)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:118)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Actuall throwing part:

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        thrown -->boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.R;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.model.User;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.utils.GeoLocationManager;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.view.PageTransformer;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.view.drawer.adapter.DrawerListAdapter;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.view.drawer.model.DrawerItem;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.view.hubFragments.AddFragment;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.view.hubFragments.LanceListFragment;
import com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.view.hubFragments.ListAllFragment;
public class HubActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AddFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ListAllFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hub);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        String[] navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        TypedArray navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        ArrayList<DrawerItem> navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

And related XML file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg1"
        tools:context="com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.activities.HubActivity">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary_material_dark"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <!-- Profile Box -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Rishabh"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="View Profile"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/black"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: Debugger]

Comment: can you please write which is line (HubActivity.java:183) . From the error I understand that the type of your layoutParams is wrong, but I can't find them in the code

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova I updated the post and marked problematic part. It's in the onPrepareOptionsMenu

thrown -->boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

Comment: @anil I'm not importing any of that stuff :>

Comment: Your tutorial is 2 yo. Prefer this one : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: @HugoGresse I don't want to use v21 stuff just yet... My app has to by compatibile with v18+ :<

Comment: @Haito If you use AppCompatV7, your app will still be compatible from v7. See https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Is this your actual layout file? You have put the `ViewPager` inside the `DrawerLayout`, is this deliberate? You also have  two `xmlns:android` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mDrawerList should be directly in the DrawerLayout and that's why it says to you that the layout params can not be cast. Your xml should look like this in the example you posted that you use so something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg1"
        tools:context="com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.activities.HubActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary_material_dark"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/home_drawer_cv_banks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="Some Dummy Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" >
    </ListView>
```

Take a look again into the example you gave http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

P.S. Another way, without changing your xml is to pass to the isDrawerOpen method your LinearLayout in which is the ListView but which is directly into your DrawerLayout, so this is the one that has a RelativeLayout in it. See this question [What do you need to pass to v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen()/.openDrawer()/.closeDrawer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289395/what-do-you-need-to-pass-to-v4-widget-drawerlayout-isdraweropen-opendrawer)

Comment: Ok.. I aplied it, but i can't get it to work properly... I have updated my XML I'm trying to make something like this:
http://codetheory.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Screenshot_2015-02-01-19-30-28.png
But the part with "current profile" isn't showing at all..
Thx for help with this crush, but could you help me also with getting this drawer to work completely?

Comment: what is not showing properly on the "current profile" part?